# Is it known that BQP is not contained within NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, bqp

I recently stumbled upon this paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.10398) and [here on the "deep ai" website](https://deepai.org/publication/bqp-is-not-in-np) that claims "BQP is not in NP."

I thought that this result would be huge (as a corollary would be that $BQP \neq P$), so I find it strange that I haven't heard about the proof before.

Is this paper legit?

Comment: This question was closed as per the following journal paper:
https://doi.org/10.1016/S0020-0190(99)00084-8
That is, BQP=/=NP

Comment: @lin: I am a little bit unsure because in the abstract it is stated that *BQP differs from NQP* . However NP and NQP are different classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no known relationship of BQP and NP. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQP) is up to date on the relationship of BQP to other classes.

The pdf you linked is not a peer-reviewed publication, and should not be believed.